# deleting a node in linked list,if the element is not there then the function clears the whole list and i am unable to get it back

Tags: c++, linked-list

```cpp
void DeleteInBetween(node **head,int data_to_be_deleted){
    
    node *newnode= (*head);
    while ((((newnode)->next)->data!=data_to_be_deleted)and (newnode!=NULL))
    {
        (newnode)=(newnode)->next;
    }
    if (newnode!=NULL)
    {
        node *nw=(newnode)->next;
        (newnode)->next=((newnode)->next)->next;
        free(nw); 
    }
}
```

the code is working fine for the linked list if the element that has to be deleted is in the list but if the element is not there then the function clears the whole list and iI am unable to get it back. Help me with the error.

Comment: Don't post images of code. Code is text and should be part of the question itself. Also your question should contain a [mre] instead of a snippet

Comment: You need to check for null pointers before dereferencing. Doing it afterwards is of no help. You also need to check `newnode->next`. (And ease up on the parentheses. And don't use `free` and `malloc` in C++ code.)

Comment: Assuming you are passing `&head` as first argument to your DeleteInBetween() function, if yes, then you will change the head pointer, since you are traversing through that itself. You have to pass a copy of the head pointer, so that it doesn't change because of the node traversal in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The below will be searching for the node with given data, it will delete the first node that has this data, and delete that node only and return. If there was a need to delete any number of nodes that has this data, then you need to modify the function, but this is a good start for you.

```
node* DeleteInBetween(node **head, int data_to_del)
{
    node *temp;
    //check if searched data is in the head node.
    if((*head)->data == data_to_del)
    {
        temp = *head;    //backup to free the memory
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);  //in c, for c++ you could call delete
        return *head; //this is the new head
    }
    else
    {
        node *current  = *head;
        while(current->next != NULL)
        {
            if(current->next->data == data_to_del)
            {
                temp = current->next;
                //node will be disconnected from the linked list.
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free(temp);
                break;
            }
            //Otherwise, move the current node and proceed
            else
                current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```